# Time out issue in Cassandra when one node is down

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I got the following error when one of the seed node in Cassandara cluster went down, the cluster has 2 data centers with 6 nodes in each DC and a replication factor of 3

```
ReadTimeoutException: Cassandra timeout during read query at consistency ALL (6 responses were required but only 5 replica responded)
```

ConsistencyLevel in the java code has been set to local_quorum:

```
.withQueryOptions(new QueryOptions().setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.**LOCAL_QUORUM**)
```

So, my undrestanding is even if one node is down in DC1, still the application should be able to query the database since RF is 3 and 5 nodes are up in DC1 and 6 nodes in DC2 as well, wondering what I'm missing in the configuration of Cassandra that caused the timeout issue even one node is down?

Comment: Your understanding is right. Please check that no query is running with quorum all. Looks like one of your query is running with consistency all. Please check it that none of your query is running with ALL consistency level. Otherwise it is not possible

Answer (score 0):

Based on the limited information you provided, I suspect that your cluster gets overloaded from time to time and nodes are dropping mutations. As a result replicas are inconsistent so when you read the data and read repair chance is enabled, a read-repair is triggered with a consistency of `ALL` (see [Read repair in Cassandra](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.x/cassandra/operations/opsRepairNodesReadRepair.html)).

This is obviously problematic even when only one replica is unavailable. As a workaround, you should set both `read_repair_chance` and `dclocal_read_repair_chance` to 0 to disable them on the problematic tables but this won't really solve the real problem.

You need to address the underlying issue which is your cluster doesn't have enough capacity so you should review the throughput of your `commitlog/` disks and consider adding more nodes to your cluster. Cheers!